# Use keyboard drawables

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm working on a layout that looks like a numeric keyboard.

I was looking around in my folder:

> C:\Program Files\Android\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable-mdpi

And I found some drawables like sym_keyboard_feedback_ok or sym_keyboard_num(1-9) that I could use :)

[image]

But when I type

> android.R.drawable.

There are no drawables that start with sym_keyboard..

How can I access those drawables without copying them manually to my resource folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was looking for the same thing but then I realized that all R.drawables are not accessible. If you look at the [android.R.drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html) reference you will not found those items that you are looking for. Also this [sample](http://mgmblog.com/2008/12/12/listing-androids-drawable-resources/) shows all accessible drawables in a list which might be useful.

In the given sample, there is a for loop, if you change the loop's interval in the following way you might found those items (in my case, I see drawables that start with sym_keyboard):

```
for (int idx = 17301504; idx <= 17303380; idx++) {
        data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            String stg = Resources.getSystem().getResourceName(idx);
            data.put("line1", stg);
            data.put("line2", idx);
            data.put("img", idx);
            resourceNames.add(data);
        }
        catch (Resources.NotFoundException nfe) {
        }
    }
```

At the end, this approach is not suggested because the drawable references might be different in different APIs so I was forced to copy my favorite drawables to the project and use them as regular drawables.

[image: Drawables on HTC Sensation with ics 4.0]